# Flutter: image.file not shown

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I use the [photo 0.2.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/photo#-readme-tab-) from system to get the photo, but when I got the photos and refreshed the interface, there was a blank.

**Code:**

```
PhotoPicker.pickAsset(
  context: context,
  // BuildContext required
  /// The following are optional parameters.
  themeColor: Colors.white,
  // the title color and bottom color
  padding: 4.0,
  //...
  //...
).then((List<AssetEntity> imgList) {
  //
  getPhotoFile(imgList);
});
```

**Get the file to List photoList**

```
List<File> photoList = [];
getPhotoFile(List<AssetEntity> imgList) async {
  for (int i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    AssetEntity item = imgList[i];
    File tempFile = await item.file;
    photoList.add(tempFile);
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

**Refresh the UI**

```
photoList.map<Widget>((File file) {
  return new FutureBuilder(
    future: _getLocalFile(file),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
      return snapshot.data != null ? new Image.file(snapshot.data) : new Container();
        })
          : new Container();
    });
}.toList();

Future<File> _getLocalFile(File file) async {
  return file;
}
```

I get file.path like

```
'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/543EEE91-BD94-4EA7-969C-A4E3320C4B93/tmp/.images/3609017ffc0170a5968fc9edbb44eb9c.jpg'
```

What should I do to ensure that all pictures are displayed?

[image]

Comment: who can help me?

Comment: Hello, did you fix that? I have the same problem on IOS, it works well on android

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the result of flutter doctor -v ?
Could you wrap your Image.
file with a container ?
here's an example.

```
child: Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.teal),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Image.file(
```